# ECDH sunEC Encryption and Decryption for String Value

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption, java-security, ecdh

I am using this code to generate my private and public key (using Java), and I need to use it to encrypt and decrypt strings:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "SunEC");
ECGenParameterSpec ecParameterSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(ecParameterSpec);
KeyPair ecdhKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = ecdhKeyPair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = ecdhKeyPair.getPublic();
```

Assuming I have a string I want to encrypt and decrypt using the public key, how do I do that? I have been looking all around, and I cant seem to find the answer. Really, I am looking for the 2 functions that look like this:

```
public String encryptString(PublicKey publicKey, String stringToEncrypt){
}
```

and

```
public String decryptString(PrivateKey privateKey, String stringToDecrypt){
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: ECDH is not an encryption algorithm. You can _combine_ it with a symmetric cipher, and that's what ECIES does, but SunEC (and other usual Sun./Oracle/OpenJDK providers) doesn't implement ECIES.

Comment: Gotcha! thx :) What cipher would you recommend for encrypting and decrypting a string with EC?

Comment: No, you'd still use ECIES. ECIES is just basically DH with the public key of the receiver, and an ephemeral key pair for each message. You derive the secret key using normal DH key agreement, encrypt the message with it, *and attach the public key* with the encrypted message, and destroy the private key. The receiver can now perform the same DH key agreement which generates the same secret key, and decrypt. Key agreement and symmetric encryption both **are** part of the standard set of implemented algorithms. By the way, the `getInstance("EC", "SunEC")` is better just as `getInstance("EC")`.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes Oh! Understood. I was originally using RSA, because for the purposes of this question, I was going to generate a public key (that remains static), and use it to encrypt logs incoming to my API, should there be an exception/attack. However, in the case that my database is breached, only I am able to recover the logs. I am not using symmetrical encryption, because, obviously it would require keeping the key on the server itself (which may be breached). I stopped using RSA due to how computationally intensive it is to encrypt, so I was wondering what is a much faster alternative?

Comment: Not sure if that's going to work; RSA public key operations are relatively fast compared to other asymmetric primitives. It's the key generation that is very slow and unpredictable (finding primes) and private key operations are slow as well. But encryption just uses public keys, so it should be fast even compared to e.g. ECIES.